# How to get row List elements compare by two rows Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have spreadsheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qjvn90lZ7AWhYApChd2gAKHzZqmnNz4xlURENSQasaw/edit#gid=0 and i want to get rows with some differences by unique values *Id* and *Updated at*.

List №1 i have the same automatic importing data http://prntscr.com/t3axvt
In List №3 i try to use `=UNIQUE('List1'!A2:A;'List1'!D2:D)` http://prntscr.com/t3ayx8 but it didn't work

**Question**
i need to get rows from List1 if there are duplicates with these parameters *Id* and *Updated at* first row  from duplicate rows (must be like this http://prntscr.com/t3b3nb) or last row from duplicate rows (must be like this http://prntscr.com/t3b3nb).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a helper column to achieve this

Create a helper **column J** and put the below formula in **J2**

```
=arrayformula(if(D2:D7=OFFSET(D2:D7,-1,0),"",ROW(A2:A7)))
```

Then you'll be able to filter your data, put below formula in **A10**

```
=FILTER(A2:J7,J2:J7<>"")
```

Please amend your data ranges per your requirement

Please use `;` instead of `,` if you in are different continent

[image]

for Extended Range, use below formula

```
=arrayformula(if(D2:D="","", if(D2:D=OFFSET(D2:D1000,-1,0),"",ROW(A2:A))))
```

Comment: Thanks, but i have syntaxerror after putting formulas http://prntscr.com/t3gf1i in created Helper-Column and error in Filtered Result http://prntscr.com/t3gfv4 ? and how can i show Filtered Result data ranges put in the List3 spreadsheet with A1:I1 head column with the same name Id, Name ... not Filtered Result

Comment: You are in different continent, please replace `,` with `;`, I have updated the formula in your sheet

Comment: thanks it works perfect, i have a last quetion - how to get in this formula =arrayformula(if(D2:D=OFFSET(D2:D;-1;0);"";ROW(A2:A)))  take rows from D2 to the last existing element D and in OFFSET (D2: to last existing) and in ROW(A2: to last existing)

Comment: Didn't get your question, do u want to change the range in formula or else?

Comment: yes, i have update data in spreadsheet in real time so i need auto change the range from `D2:D7` (D7 change to last existing, today it may be `D100 -> D2:D100`, tomorrow will be `D214 -> D2:D100` etc) in `OFFSET` and in `ROW(A2:A7)` where A7 change to last existing `A100 -> A2:A100` , tomorrow A214) for example LIST1 today have 25 records [link]http://prntscr.com/t3r0wv[/link] - i need change formula again `to =arrayformula(if(D2:D25=OFFSET(D2:D25;-1;0);"";ROW(A2:A25))) `

Comment: yes, in that case, you can use this formula `=arrayformula(if(D2:D="","", if(D2:D=OFFSET(D2:D1000,-1,0),"",ROW(A2:A))))`

Comment: @DamirShaykxutd remember to upvote and/or accept answers that have solved your problem and may be useful for others.

Comment: @Rocky how can i change range in OFFSET(D2:D1000 - do D1000 auto increase value, if i have today 25 records so OFFSET(D2:D25), after two hours 57 i need OFFSET(D2:D57) and etc

Comment: @Damir Shaykxutd you can try this formula -`=ARRAYFORMULA(if(D2:D="","", if(D2:D=OFFSET(Indirect("D2:D"&counta(D2:D)&+1),-1,0),"",ROW(A2:A))))`